# How can I reduce the bandwidth required to get an XML file in Flash?

Tags: xml, flash

I use a movieclip in flash that makes requests of an XML file through GET (port 80) each second. The file size is 2kB. How can I reduce the required bandwidth? The movieclip timeline is already adjusted for 1frame/s.

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more detail to get an answer.  Example question: Is the content dynamically generated?  Another one: What sort of data is being loaded (text, images, audio)?

Comment: Yes, loaded images and text. The xml's content is dynamically generated to each 1 second.

Answer (score 3):

Gzip it. Remove whitespace. Shorten tags where possible. Switch to a less verbose format like JSON. Change your logic so you can request it less frequently.